# Using LDAC in Ubuntuu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, bluetooth

I have recently upgraded to ubuntu 20.04. I want to use my bluetooth headphones in ldac mode. Is there a way to do that? My headphones support ldac.

Comment: Hi you may want to read this article which a quick google search found. https://www.programmersought.com/article/79165113111/

Comment: Thank You @David